# Which one is correct? "had to go" vs "had to went"

Tags: past-tense

Which one should I use?

I **had to go** to see my friend.

I **had to went** to see my friend.

Comment: No details are necessary to answer this question.  The infinitive form *go* is expected here, as P. E. Dant has explained below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, at first glance, to think of *have to* in usages like this one as a *phrasal verb.* It looks like one, but it's not. The *to* in *have to* is not a preposition, and it's not the *to* which might be part of the infinitive which follows. (See StoneyB's test for "phrasalness" [**here.**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/152225/192771))

In your sentences, the usage of the past tense of the verb *to have* is a example of its rôle as part of an idiomatic ***modal auxiliary*** which expresses obligation. It is often rendered as *ˈhæftə* in NAmE speech; the past tense *had to*  is rendered as *'hædə.* (See [“have to” a phrasal verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/152217/192771) at our sister site ELU.)

As [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler) says in his comment at ELU:

> In fact, *have to* is an [idiomatic modal auxiliary](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf), paraphrasing *must.* It is certainly not a [phrasal verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/370/Englishphrasalverbs.pdf), which has completely different syntax.

When used in this way, *have to* takes the bare infinitive of the verb (in this case **go.**):

> I **had to *go*** to see my friend.

More examples:

> I **have to *spend*** a week in the country.
>   I **had to *study*** the instructions.

*Have to* cannot take the *simple past* form of the verb as in your second example.

Comment: Unexplained downvotes don't advance the OP's understanding. If there is a shortcoming in this answer, please let us know what it is so that it can be corrected!

Comment: It could be because *have* is not a modal auxiliary.  You might consider looking up the term "semi-modal". *Have to* is grammatically distinct from the modal auxiliaries in lacking most of the modal auxiliary properties, for example in having secondary (non-finite) forms. It is semantically quite similar though, so it's been called a "semi-modal" or "periphrastic modal".

Comment: @snailplane Mercy! I did not know that the prevailing view of _have to_ is apposite to that of [John Lawler.](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/152217/192771) Is this a minor jurisdictional dispute, or a colloquy of longstanding? I don't want to get in the middle of a factional slap fight, but the paper to which he links in his comments seems persuasive to me. I have to ... er, agree with Lawler and StoneyB here.

Comment: For more information, see *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* p.106 under *Distinctive properties of the modal auxiliaries* and p.111 for *have to*, or *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* p.137 under *Verbs of intermediate function* (semi-auxiliaries, "verbs whose status is in some degree intermediate between auxiliaries and main verbs").  (The book I recommended earlier, *Meaning and the English Verb*, focuses on meaning and this is a grammatical detail, so it doesn't really cover it.)  I of course am not disagreeing with StoneyB here.

Comment: What John Lawler unfortunately calls an 'idiomatic modal auxiliary' is not the same as a 'modal auxiliary'; rather, it is a term for what he refers to in his worksheet as a 'paraphrase of a modal auxiliary'.  (Lawler isn't incorrect, it's just a confusing choice of terminology.)  It lacks most of the grammatical modal auxiliary properties (having only primary forms, not displaying agreement, taking bare rather than *to* infinitival complementation, being grammatical in the apodosis of a remote conditional), so it can't really be considered part of the same grammatical class.

Comment: I'm familiar with CGEL on this, but I still agree with Lawler and with StoneyB.  What is it about Lawler's explanation that you find unpersuasive? _Have to_ is included [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf) as a logical modal, and I can't find anything to disagree with in the presentation. I don't find anything unfortunate in his comment, myself. It seems succinct and correct to me.

Comment: I didn't say I disagreed with Lawler or StoneyB, only with your answer.  Lawler himself does not include *have* as a modal auxiliary, only as (as you point out) a "logical modal" (a set which includes but is not limited to the modal auxiliaries; it also includes paraphrases of the modal auxiliaries which lack their grammatical properties, such as *have to*).  If you read more carefully, you will notice that you are incorrect.  For further information, please see the resources above.  I will not respond or explain further, since you have all the information you need at this point.